# Breadcrumb navigation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, breadcrumb

I would like to ask you if is it possible to display breadcrumb navigation in SharePoint Online as in [this post](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/)?

I would like to use this navigation also as a next-one navigation element for users through the portal. I think its really practical element for end-users.